# What is the incentive for people running execution clients in eth2?

Tags: proof-of-stake, proof-of-work, validators, beacon-chain

If I understand correctly, in the coming proof of stake version of Ethereum, there would be the beacon chain, with blocks on it created by validators. These validators will get compensated for doing this.

There would also be another chain (execution chain) where clients like Geth will create blocks that contain transactions information and where smart contracts are executed. Previously operators of these clients get rewarded based on the proof of work consensus model. But with the move to PoS, and validators providing security (and getting rewarded for it) where does the incentive for folks running clients like Geth now come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validators will need to run execution layer (EL) clients because consensus layer (CL) clients don't create blocks with transactions and execute smart contracts.

There is more discussion at:
https://old.reddit.com/r/ethstaker/comments/vv80qf/help_me_understand_why_technically_could_a/

> This really is no different from how things work now in PoW, just that the consensus code is inside the EL in PoW. Every execution client comes with consensus layer code for PoW and PoA included. That 1:1 relationship continues, just that now the consensus is in an external client.

---

Also note that not everyone that is running a client like Geth today, is a miner.